# Cloning a git repository from my machine to another through ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I might be overcomplicating this a lot, but I have a git repo on my machine, and I've got another machine at work I usually connect to for work. Every once in a while I need to get some code that I mainly develop in my machine to this work machine, and I would like to just use git instead of copying the code with scp or rsync so that I can keep track of versions and so on.

So to clone the repo, I thought I would have to reverse ssh into the work machine, and then again clone the git repo through the reversed ssh connection.

A test could be

```
mkdir testgit && cd testgit
touch file
git init
git add file
git commit -m "test commit"
```

This in the local machine. Now what I was trying (but doesn't work) is

```
localmachine  $ ssh -R 43022:localhost:22 user@remote
remotemachine $ git clone ssh://user@localhost:43022/home/user/testgit/
```

This however always gives me `Connection reset by peer`, so I don't think I really understand what this reversed connection is doing. What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to clone to remote, especially in such a overcomplicated way, you just need to push.

On the remote side there have to be 2 repositories — bare and non-bare. Bare repo is where you push to from the local repo. Non-bare repo is a repo with working tree (checked out files) where you pull from bare.

Create a new empty bare and non-bare repositories; push to bare from the local one:

```
ssh user@remote -p 43022 "
    cd /home/user &&
    git init --bare testgit.git &&
    git init testgit &&
    cd testgit &&
    git remote add bare ../testgit.git"
git remote add work ssh://user@remote:43022/home/user/testgit.git
git push -u work master # or how do call your master branch
```

Pull from bare to non-bare:

```
ssh user@remote -p 43022 "cd /home/user/testgit && git pull bare master"
```

You can automate the last step using a `post-receive` or `post-update` hook in the bare repo.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I was overcomplicating it. However if I try to push to it I get a git error "refusing to update checked out branch refs/heads/master" saying I should set the receive.denyCurrentBranch to ignore and that this is not recommended because by default updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied. What's the proper way to set up the empty remote repository? (I tested this with your exact commands, with a fresh local git repo with a single file and a single commit as in my original question)

Comment: Oops, I've forgotten — the remote repo to push to must be **bare**. Updated the answer. Now it looks much more complicated. :-(

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the detailed answer! Exactly what I need